# I can't print a specific set in a list in python

Tags: python

```
coordinates=[(4,5),(5,6,(6,6))]
print(coordinates[3])

result:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\App.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(coordinates[3])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I want the result to be [6,6] instead of the error message what do you mean i am trying to access a fourth one I am trying to access the 3rd one in the list when i use coordinates[1][2] it gives me a syntax error

Comment: `coordinates` has only two tuples inside it. You're trying to access a 4th one which doesn't exist.

Comment: Your list has 2 elements: tuples. .

Comment: Then perhaps you want `coordinates[1][2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to double check the way you formatted your list.
From the looks of it, your list has index 0 (4,5) and index 1 (5,6,(6,6)). Your list simply has nothing at index 3 because there are only 2 entries. That's what the error message means.

You might want to change your list into `coordinates=[(4,5),5,6,(6,6)]`, then you have index 0-3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
print(coordinates[1][-1])
or 
print(coordinates[1][2])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems:

(1) Items in a list are **zero-indexed**, meaning the first element of L is L[0], second is L[1], etc. So if you want the *third* item:

```
print(coordinates[2])
```

(2) If you just stop there, you'll still get an `index out of range` exception, because your list has only 2 elements. I think you've misplaced a `)`:

```
coordinates=[(4,5),(5,6),(6,6)]
```

In your question, your list `coordinates` has 2 elements: `(4, 5)` and `(5, 6, (6, 6))` - notice the nested parentheses. The second item is the set containing 3 elements: `5`, `6`, and another set `(6,6)`.

Tip: Sometimes I like to put lists on multiple lines, especially if they are nested or contain sets/tuples/other complicated structures. One widely accepted style for this is shown below:

```
coordinates = [
    (4,5),
    (5,6),
    (6,6),
]
```

EDIT: Thanks to [Ignatius Reilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15032126/ignatius-reilly) for catching my missing commas!
Note: you are allowed to have a comma after the last element, which I usually do. It makes it easier to add more elements or rearrange them later using copy/paste.

Comment: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable is what it gives me